# Unknown painting of a lady

Tags: meaning, character-identification, seal

I bought a painting on a French flee-market and and I would very much like to know who the painter is. The text is translate by someone who is very good at translating Chinese text and seals, but she cannot find the right painter. That's why I'm making another attempt.

Greeting Moon

瑪曲乾實成会魚師　陽陰写生於甘南
今憶星一品　於庚午春日寒旅憓客下
I actually met a fisher(wo)man of Maqu and sketched her facing the sun in Gannan
Now, I consider it as a star piece of my sketchings. In the Year of Metal-Horse (1990)
at spring cold which brings its benefit to the traveller.

Upper seal,
鴻　(Hong)    Swan goose   - Pseudonym
Lower seal,
小朗畫　-　Picture of  Xiaolang   -  Given name  (Female)
The Xiao Lang on the artnet with chicken paintings is a different artist.
蕭朗 Xiao Lang  -　Surname and given name.    Your artist is 小朗  -  Given name only.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, I might say this painter might not be very famous, since you didn't find his/her name on the Internet. His/her painting is drawn in 1990 in Maqu County, Southern Gansu Province, which is quite remote and poor.